# Agrupar elementos de un JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tengo el siguiente JSON , el cual cada registro tiene un ciudad , pero la misma ciudad puede estar en muchos registros a la vez.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "numero": "123",
      "nombre": "jorge",
      "ciudad": "Tokio"
    },
    {
      "numero": "222",
      "nombre": "juan",
      "ciudad": "Tokio"
    },
    {
      "numero": "777",
      "nombre": "daniel",
      "ciudad": "Tokio"
    },
    {
      "numero": "333",
      "nombre": "pedro",
      "ciudad": "New york"
    },
    {
      "numero": "444",
      "nombre": "luis",
      "ciudad": "New york"
    },
    {
      "numero": "555",
      "nombre": "andres",
      "ciudad": "Buenos Aires"
    }
  ]
}
```

Necesito poder agrupar por ciudad y solo mostrar 1 de ellas independiente de las veces que esta se repita ademas traer el numero de elementos encontrados ejemplo:

> resultado : (Tokio,New york,Buenos Aires,3)
>
> /* "3" es el numero de ciudades encontradas */

Muchas gracias por su atención , estaré atento a sus repuestas saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con un Map, ya que nunca se repetirá la clave, y como valor puedes utilizar un array de objetos.

```
const data = {
"data": [
{
  "numero": "123",
  "nombre": "jorge",
  "ciudad": "Tokio"
},
{
  "numero": "222",
  "nombre": "juan",
  "ciudad": "Tokio"
},
{
  "numero": "777",
  "nombre": "daniel",
  "ciudad": "Tokio"
},
{
  "numero": "333",
  "nombre": "pedro",
  "ciudad": "New york"
},
{
  "numero": "444",
  "nombre": "luis",
  "ciudad": "New york"
},
{
  "numero": "555",
  "nombre": "andres",
  "ciudad": "Buenos Aires"
}
]
}

const map = data.data.reduce((map, item) => map.set(item.ciudad, item), new Map());

console.log(map.get('Buenos Aires').length);//1
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo iterando por tus datos y generando un nuevo array de ciudades unicas.  Algo asi:

```js
var data = {
  "data": [
    {
      "numero": "123",
      "nombre": "jorge",
      "ciudad": "Tokio"
    },
    {
      "numero": "222",
      "nombre": "juan",
      "ciudad": "Tokio"
    },
    {
      "numero": "777",
      "nombre": "daniel",
      "ciudad": "Tokio"
    },
    {
      "numero": "333",
      "nombre": "pedro",
      "ciudad": "New york"
    },
    {
      "numero": "444",
      "nombre": "luis",
      "ciudad": "New york"
    },
    {
      "numero": "555",
      "nombre": "andres",
      "ciudad": "Buenos Aires"
    }
  ]
};

var ciudades = [];

data.data.forEach(function(dato) {
  if (ciudades.indexOf(dato.ciudad) == -1) {
    ciudades.push(dato.ciudad);
  }
});
console.log(ciudades);
console.log(ciudades.length);
```